# Add multiple domains to aws cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to point both https://app.test1.com and https://app.test2.com to a aws cloudfront distribution.

Does anyone how how to do it? I am unable to figure out how to add both domains and also both the SSL certs to a single cloud front distribution

Comment: Did you refer this http://www.bucketexplorer.com/documentation/amazon-s3--how-to-create-distributions-post-distribution-with-multiple-origin-servers.html

Answer (score 0):

You can only attach 1 one certificate to each CloudFront distribution.  If multiple domains is what you want, you need a single certificate with all the desired hostnames listed as Subject Alternative Names.  Many SSL CAs will sell you a cert like this, sometimes called multi-domain, SAN, or UC certificates.  You can also get one from Amazon Certificate Manager.

You add additional hostnames to your distribution the same way you added the first one: configure [alternate domain names](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html).  Simply using DNS CNAME records isn't enough, becaue CloudFront has to expect the hostname on the incoming request.